# Removing Trailing Zeros in Python

Tags: python, string, zero

I need to find a way to convert the following strings in python:

```
0.000       => 0
0           => 0
123.45000   => 123.45
0000        => 0
123.4506780 => 123.450678
```

and so forth. I tried .rstrip('0').rstrip('.'), but that doesn't work if the input is 0 or 00.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Try np.format_float_positional(number,trim='-'). If number is 8.0, it will removed .0 from the end

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Updated** Generalized to maintain precision and handle unseen values:

```
import decimal
import random

def format_number(num):
    try:
        dec = decimal.Decimal(num)
    except:
        return 'bad'
    tup = dec.as_tuple()
    delta = len(tup.digits) + tup.exponent
    digits = ''.join(str(d) for d in tup.digits)
    if delta <= 0:
        zeros = abs(tup.exponent) - len(tup.digits)
        val = '0.' + ('0'*zeros) + digits
    else:
        val = digits[:delta] + ('0'*tup.exponent) + '.' + digits[delta:]
    val = val.rstrip('0')
    if val[-1] == '.':
        val = val[:-1]
    if tup.sign:
        return '-' + val
    return val

# test data
NUMS = '''
    0.0000      0
    0           0
    123.45000   123.45
    0000        0
    123.4506780 123.450678
    0.1         0.1
    0.001       0.001
    0.005000    0.005
    .1234       0.1234
    1.23e1      12.3
    -123.456    -123.456
    4.98e10     49800000000
    4.9815135   4.9815135
    4e30        4000000000000000000000000000000
    -0.0000000000004 -0.0000000000004
    -.4e-12     -0.0000000000004
    -0.11112    -0.11112
    1.3.4.5     bad
    -1.2.3      bad
'''

for num, exp in [s.split() for s in NUMS.split('\n') if s]:
    res = format_number(num)
    print res
    assert exp == res
```

Output:

```
0
0
123.45
0
123.450678
0.1
0.001
0.005
0.1234
12.3
-123.456
49800000000
4.9815135
4000000000000000000000000000000
-0.0000000000004
-0.0000000000004
-0.11112
bad
bad
```

Comment: @samplebias: Any non-zero integer will have a decimal point appended to it. Using str() loses precision e.g. `str(float('.1234567890123456'))` produces `'0.123456789012'` **FAIL**

Comment: @John Ack - switched to Decimal, added a larger variety of test data.

Comment: @samplebias: Testing with random values is like firing marshmallows from a gatling. Try chosen values e.g. `0.00000000023283064365386963` which produces `2.3283064365386963E-1` which constitues a double-barrel **FAIL**

Comment: @John -ouch- that hurt. Updated for arbitrary precision.

Comment: @samplebias: Reading your latest code reveals that the test `'.' in val` is redundant -- it is always true.

Comment: @John thanks, stripped that out. Interesting to see so many takes on this; I'm still not sure what it'll be used for, or the acceptable limit on precision (government debt accounting, measurements at Planck scale?).

Comment: @samplebias All the results that I obtained with your function are correct. But the representation returned by ``format_number()`` for certain numbers like 12.5E154 or 0.0068E-47 isn't practical. The necessity is rather to have a function that does the contrary: to compress a long number string in a short notation, as the ``'{:g}'.format()`` of arrussel84 does it. By the way, it only treats strings that are numbers; it can't search them in a text.

Comment: If I use `num = 0.001`, I get back `0.00100000000000000002081...`. To fix this issue, I convert num to str. So instead of `dec = decimal.Decimal(num)`, I use `dec = decimal.Decimal(str(num))`

Answer (score 25):

You can use [format strings](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings) if you want, but be aware that you might need to set your desired precision, as format strings have their own logic for this by default. Janneb suggests a precision of 17 in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807952/removing-trailing-zeros-in-python/5808016#5808016).

```
'{:g}'.format(float(your_string_goes_here))
```

After thinking about this some more, though, I think the simplest and best solution is just to cast the string twice (as [jathanism suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807952/removing-trailing-zeros-in-python/5807995#5807995)):

```
str(float(your_string_goes_here))
```

Edit: Added clarification because of comment.

Comment: Interesting, but 10003.4506700 gives 10003.5 , 15000.0012 gives 15000, 78000.89 gives 78000.9, .1234567890123456000 gives 0.123457. However I upvote because of knowledge in format()

Answer (score 9):

For the floating point numbers, you can just cast the string to a `float`:

```
>>> float('123.4506780')
123.450678
```

For the zero values, you can just cast those to an integer:

```
>>> int('0000')
0
```

When printed, numeric values are automatically converted to strings.  If you need these to actually be strings, you may simply cast them back to strings with `str()`, e.g.:

```
>>> str(float('123.4506780'))
'123.450678'
```

Comment: With float he could lose precision. Better to use doubles.

Comment: Python doesn't have doubles! Floating point numbers are implemented using double in C.

Comment: whooops now I feel profound shame ;) thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: Haha that's ok! There's no shame in learning. I get schooled all the time.

Comment: Good answer for truncating trailing zeros from a float.

Comment: This does not truncate `0.0` into `'0'` as requested

Answer (score 4):

```
'%.17g' % float(mystr)
```

depending on what you actually want to do..

Comment: Loses precision by default: `'%g' % 1.23456789, str(1.23456789)` results: `('1.23457', '1.23456789')`

Comment: @samplebias: Improved precision, 17 significant digits is enough for IEEE binary64. Fundamentally, this doesn't of course help for cases where the number isn't exactly representable in FP.

Answer (score 1):

### FIRST "SOLUTION"

```
import re
regx=re.compile('(?<![\d.])'
                '(?!\d*\.\d*\.)'  # excludes certain string as not being numbers
                '((\d|\.\d)([\d.])*?)'  # the only matching  group
                '([0\.]*)'
                '(?![\d.])')
regx.sub('\\1',ch)
```

.

### EDIT 1

John Machin said that 10000 and 10000.000 produce 1 instead of 10000

I corrected the replacement function with the help of `(?!(?<=0)\.)`

```
import re
regx = re.compile('(?<![\d.])'       '(?![1-9]\d*(?![\d.])|\d*\.\d*\.)'
                  '0*(?!(?<=0)\.)'
                  '([\d.]+?)'      # the only group , which is kept
                  '\.?0*'
                  '(?![\d.])')    
regx.sub('\\1',ch)
```

.

### EDIT 2

To correct the remaining shortcomings [ **'.0000'** producing **'.'** , pointed out by John Machin, and **'000078000'** producing **'78'** ] , I rewrote a regex build on a new idea. It's simpler. The regex detects all types of numbers.

This solution not only cuts the trailing zeros off, but also the heading zeros.
Here's the comparison of this solution with John Machin's `tidy_float()` ,  samplebias's `number_format()` , arussell84's `'{:g}'.format()` . There are some differences between the results of my function (all correct this time) and the others :

```
import re
def number_shaver(ch,
                  regx = re.compile('(?<![\d.])0*(?:'
                                    '(\d+)\.?|\.(0)'
                                    '|(\.\d+?)|(\d+\.\d+?)'
                                    ')0*(?![\d.])')  ,
                  repl = lambda mat: mat.group(mat.lastindex)
                                     if mat.lastindex!=3
                                     else '0' + mat.group(3) ):
    return regx.sub(repl,ch)


def tidy_float(s):  # John Machin
    """Return tidied float representation.
    Remove superflous leading/trailing zero digits.
    Remove '.' if value is an integer.
    Return '****' if float(s) fails.
    """
    # float?
    try:
        f = float(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s
    # int?
    try:
        i = int(s)
        return str(i)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    # scientific notation?
    if 'e' in s or 'E' in s:
        t = s.lstrip('0')
        if t.startswith('.'): t = '0' + t
        return t
    # float with integral value (includes zero)?
    i = int(f)
    if i == f:
        return str(i)
    assert '.' in s
    t = s.strip('0')
    if t.startswith('.'): t = '0' + t
    if t.endswith('.'): t += '0'
    return t


def format_float(s):  # arrussell84
    return '{:g}'.format(float(s)) if s.count('.')<2 \
           else "Can't treat"


import decimal
def format_number(num):
    try:
        dec = decimal.Decimal(num)
    except:
        return 'bad'
    tup = dec.as_tuple()
    delta = len(tup.digits) + tup.exponent
    digits = ''.join(str(d) for d in tup.digits)
    if delta <= 0:
        zeros = abs(tup.exponent) - len(tup.digits)
        val = '0.' + ('0'*zeros) + digits
    else:
        val = digits[:delta] + ('0'*tup.exponent) + '.' + digits[delta:]
    val = val.rstrip('0')
    if val[-1] == '.':
        val = val[:-1]
    if tup.sign:
        return '-' + val
    return val


numbers = ['23456000', '23456000.', '23456000.000',
           '00023456000', '000023456000.', '000023456000.000',
           '10000', '10000.', '10000.000',
           '00010000', '00010000.', '00010000.000',
           '24', '24.', '24.000',
           '00024', '00024.', '00024.000',
           '8', '8.', '8.000',
           '0008', '0008.', '0008.000',
           '0', '00000', '0.', '000.',
           '\n',
           '0.0', '0.000', '000.0', '000.000', '.000000', '.0',
           '\n',
           '.00023456', '.00023456000', '.00503', '.00503000',
           '.068', '.0680000', '.8', '.8000',
           '.123456123456', '.123456123456000',
           '.657', '.657000', '.45', '.4500000', '.7', '.70000',
           '\n',
           '0.0000023230000', '000.0000023230000',
           '0.0081000', '0000.0081000',
           '0.059000', '0000.059000',
           '0.78987400000', '00000.78987400000',
           '0.4400000', '00000.4400000',
           '0.5000', '0000.5000',
           '0.90', '000.90', '0.7', '000.7',
           '\n',
           '2.6', '00002.6', '00002.60000',
           '4.71', '0004.71', '0004.7100',
           '23.49', '00023.49', '00023.490000',
           '103.45', '0000103.45', '0000103.45000',
           '10003.45067', '000010003.45067', '000010003.4506700',
           '15000.0012', '000015000.0012', '000015000.0012000',
           '78000.89', '000078000.89', '000078000.89000',
           '\n',
           '.0457e10', '.0457000e10','00000.0457000e10',
           '258e8', '2580000e4', '0000000002580000e4',
           # notice the difference of exponents
           '0.782e10', '0000.782e10', '0000.7820000e10',
           '1.23E2', '0001.23E2', '0001.2300000E2',
           '432e-102', '0000432e-102', '004320000e-106',
           # notice the difference of exponents
           '1.46e10', '0001.46e10', '0001.4600000e10',
           '1.077e-300', '0001.077e-300', '0001.077000e-300',
           '1.069e10', '0001.069e10', '0001.069000e10',
           '105040.03e10', '000105040.03e10', '105040.0300e10',
           '\n',
           '..18000', '25..00',  '36...77', '2..8',
           '3.8..9', '.12500.', '12.51.400' ]
```

pat = '%18s  %-15s %-15s %-15s %s'
li = [pat % ('tested number','float_shaver',
             'tidy_float',"format_number()","'{:g}'.format()")]
li.extend(pat % (n,number_shaver(n),tidy_float(n),format_number(n),format_float(n))
          if n!='\n' else '\n' for n in numbers)

print '\n'.join(li)

result of the comparison:

```
     tested number  float_shaver    tidy_float      format_number() '{:g}'.format()
          23456000  23456000        23456000        23456000        2.3456e+07
         23456000.  23456000        23456000        23456000        2.3456e+07
      23456000.000  23456000        23456000        23456000        2.3456e+07
       00023456000  23456000        23456000        23456000        2.3456e+07
     000023456000.  23456000        23456000        23456000        2.3456e+07
  000023456000.000  23456000        23456000        23456000        2.3456e+07
             10000  10000           10000           10000           10000
            10000.  10000           10000           10000           10000
         10000.000  10000           10000           10000           10000
          00010000  10000           10000           10000           10000
         00010000.  10000           10000           10000           10000
      00010000.000  10000           10000           10000           10000
                24  24              24              24              24
               24.  24              24              24              24
            24.000  24              24              24              24
             00024  24              24              24              24
            00024.  24              24              24              24
         00024.000  24              24              24              24
                 8  8               8               8               8
                8.  8               8               8               8
             8.000  8               8               8               8
              0008  8               8               8               8
             0008.  8               8               8               8
          0008.000  8               8               8               8
                 0  0               0               0               0
             00000  0               0               0               0
                0.  0               0               0               0
              000.  0               0               0               0


               0.0  0               0               0               0
             0.000  0               0               0               0
             000.0  0               0               0               0
           000.000  0               0               0               0
           .000000  0               0               0               0
                .0  0               0               0               0


         .00023456  0.00023456      0.00023456      0.00023456      0.00023456
      .00023456000  0.00023456      0.00023456      0.00023456      0.00023456
            .00503  0.00503         0.00503         0.00503         0.00503
         .00503000  0.00503         0.00503         0.00503         0.00503
              .068  0.068           0.068           0.068           0.068
          .0680000  0.068           0.068           0.068           0.068
                .8  0.8             0.8             0.8             0.8
             .8000  0.8             0.8             0.8             0.8
     .123456123456  0.123456123456  0.123456123456  0.123456123456  0.123456
  .123456123456000  0.123456123456  0.123456123456  0.123456123456  0.123456
              .657  0.657           0.657           0.657           0.657
           .657000  0.657           0.657           0.657           0.657
               .45  0.45            0.45            0.45            0.45
          .4500000  0.45            0.45            0.45            0.45
                .7  0.7             0.7             0.7             0.7
            .70000  0.7             0.7             0.7             0.7


   0.0000023230000  0.000002323     0.000002323     0.000002323     2.323e-06
 000.0000023230000  0.000002323     0.000002323     0.000002323     2.323e-06
         0.0081000  0.0081          0.0081          0.0081          0.0081
      0000.0081000  0.0081          0.0081          0.0081          0.0081
          0.059000  0.059           0.059           0.059           0.059
       0000.059000  0.059           0.059           0.059           0.059
     0.78987400000  0.789874        0.789874        0.789874        0.789874
 00000.78987400000  0.789874        0.789874        0.789874        0.789874
         0.4400000  0.44            0.44            0.44            0.44
     00000.4400000  0.44            0.44            0.44            0.44
            0.5000  0.5             0.5             0.5             0.5
         0000.5000  0.5             0.5             0.5             0.5
              0.90  0.9             0.9             0.9             0.9
            000.90  0.9             0.9             0.9             0.9
               0.7  0.7             0.7             0.7             0.7
             000.7  0.7             0.7             0.7             0.7


               2.6  2.6             2.6             2.6             2.6
           00002.6  2.6             2.6             2.6             2.6
       00002.60000  2.6             2.6             2.6             2.6
              4.71  4.71            4.71            4.71            4.71
           0004.71  4.71            4.71            4.71            4.71
         0004.7100  4.71            4.71            4.71            4.71
             23.49  23.49           23.49           23.49           23.49
          00023.49  23.49           23.49           23.49           23.49
      00023.490000  23.49           23.49           23.49           23.49
            103.45  103.45          103.45          103.45          103.45
        0000103.45  103.45          103.45          103.45          103.45
     0000103.45000  103.45          103.45          103.45          103.45
       10003.45067  10003.45067     10003.45067     10003.45067     10003.5
   000010003.45067  10003.45067     10003.45067     10003.45067     10003.5
 000010003.4506700  10003.45067     10003.45067     10003.45067     10003.5
        15000.0012  15000.0012      15000.0012      15000.0012      15000
    000015000.0012  15000.0012      15000.0012      15000.0012      15000
 000015000.0012000  15000.0012      15000.0012      15000.0012      15000
          78000.89  78000.89        78000.89        78000.89        78000.9
      000078000.89  78000.89        78000.89        78000.89        78000.9
   000078000.89000  78000.89        78000.89        78000.89        78000.9


          .0457e10  0.0457e10       0.0457e10       457000000       4.57e+08
       .0457000e10  0.0457e10       0.0457000e10    457000000       4.57e+08
  00000.0457000e10  0.0457e10       0.0457000e10    457000000       4.57e+08
             258e8  258e8           258e8           25800000000     2.58e+10
         2580000e4  2580000e4       2580000e4       25800000000     2.58e+10
0000000002580000e4  2580000e4       2580000e4       25800000000     2.58e+10
          0.782e10  0.782e10        0.782e10        7820000000      7.82e+09
       0000.782e10  0.782e10        0.782e10        7820000000      7.82e+09
   0000.7820000e10  0.782e10        0.7820000e10    7820000000      7.82e+09
            1.23E2  1.23E2          1.23E2          123             123
         0001.23E2  1.23E2          1.23E2          123             123
    0001.2300000E2  1.23E2          1.2300000E2     123             123
          432e-102  432e-102        432e-102        0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000432 4.32e-100
      0000432e-102  432e-102        432e-102        0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000432 4.32e-100
    004320000e-106  4320000e-106    4320000e-106    0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000432 4.32e-100
           1.46e10  1.46e10         1.46e10         14600000000     1.46e+10
        0001.46e10  1.46e10         1.46e10         14600000000     1.46e+10
   0001.4600000e10  1.46e10         1.4600000e10    14600000000     1.46e+10
        1.077e-300  1.077e-300      1.077e-300      0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001077 1.077e-300
     0001.077e-300  1.077e-300      1.077e-300      0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001077 1.077e-300
  0001.077000e-300  1.077e-300      1.077000e-300   0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001077 1.077e-300
          1.069e10  1.069e10        1.069e10        10690000000     1.069e+10
       0001.069e10  1.069e10        1.069e10        10690000000     1.069e+10
    0001.069000e10  1.069e10        1.069000e10     10690000000     1.069e+10
      105040.03e10  105040.03e10    105040.03e10    1050400300000000 1.0504e+15
   000105040.03e10  105040.03e10    105040.03e10    1050400300000000 1.0504e+15
    105040.0300e10  105040.03e10    105040.0300e10  1050400300000000 1.0504e+15


           ..18000  ..18000         ..18000         bad             Can't treat
            25..00  25..00          25..00          bad             Can't treat
           36...77  36...77         36...77         bad             Can't treat
              2..8  2..8            2..8            bad             Can't treat
            3.8..9  3.8..9          3.8..9          bad             Can't treat
           .12500.  .12500.         .12500.         bad             Can't treat
         12.51.400  12.51.400       12.51.400       bad             Can't treat
```

.

I  consider that my solution have two advantages:

- the regex and the function **number_shave()** are short
- **number_shave()** doesn't only treat one number at a time but it also detects and treats all the numbers in a string. Here's a treatment that John Machin's and arrussel84's solutions can't do:

code:

```
numbers = [['', '23456000', '23456000.', '23456000.000 \n',
            '00023456000', '000023456000.', '000023456000.000 \n',
            '10000', '10000.', '10000.000 \n',
            '00010000', '00010000.', '00010000.000 \n',
            '24', '24.', '24.000 \n',
            '00024', '00024.', '00024.000 \n',
            '8', '8.', '8.000 \n',
            '0008', '0008.', '0008.000 \n',
            '0', '00000', '0.', '000.' ],




            ['0.0', '0.000', '000.0', '000.000', '.000000', '.0'],

            ['.00023456', '.00023456000', '.00503', '.00503000 \n',
             '.068', '.0680000', '.8', '.8000 \n',
             '.123456123456', '.123456123456000 \n',
             '.657', '.657000', '.45', '.4500000', '.7', '.70000'],

            ['0.0000023230000', '000.0000023230000 \n',
             '0.0081000', '0000.0081000 \n',
             '0.059000', '0000.059000 \n',
             '0.78987400000', '00000.78987400000 \n',
             '0.4400000', '00000.4400000 \n',
             '0.5000', '0000.5000 \n',
             '0.90', '000.90', '0.7', '000.7 '],

            ['2.6', '00002.6', '00002.60000 \n',
             '4.71', '0004.71', '0004.7100 \n',
             '23.49', '00023.49', '00023.490000 \n',
             '103.45', '0000103.45', '0000103.45000 \n',
             '10003.45067', '000010003.45067', '000010003.4506700 \n',
             '15000.0012', '000015000.0012', '000015000.0012000 \n',
             '78000.89', '000078000.89', '000078000.89000'],

            ['.0457e10', '.0457000e10 \n',
             '0.782e10', '0000.782e10', '0000.7820000e10 \n',
             '1.23E2', '0001.23E2', '0001.2300000E2 \n',
             '1.46e10', '0001.46e10', '0001.4600000e10 \n',
             '1.077e-456', '0001.077e-456', '0001.077000e-456 \n',
             '1.069e10', '0001.069e10', '0001.069000e10 \n',
             '105040.03e10', '000105040.03e10', '105040.03e10'],

            ['..18000', '25..00',  '36...77', '2..8 \n',
             '3.8..9', '.12500.', '12.51.400' ]]


import re
def number_shaver(ch,
                 regx = re.compile('(?<![\d.])0*(?:'
                                   '(\d+)\.?|\.(0)'
                                   '|(\.\d+?)|(\d+\.\d+?)'
                                   ')0*(?![\d.])')  ,
                 repl = lambda mat: mat.group(mat.lastindex)
                                    if mat.lastindex!=3
                                    else '0' + mat.group(3) ):
    return regx.sub(repl,ch)




for li in numbers:
    one_string = ' --- '.join(li)
    print one_string + '\n\n' + number_shaver(one_string) + \
          '\n\n' + 3*'---------------------' + '\n'
```

results of the treatments of strings containing several numbers:

```
 --- 23456000 --- 23456000. --- 23456000.000 
 --- 00023456000 --- 000023456000. --- 000023456000.000 
 --- 10000 --- 10000. --- 10000.000 
 --- 00010000 --- 00010000. --- 00010000.000 
 --- 24 --- 24. --- 24.000 
 --- 00024 --- 00024. --- 00024.000 
 --- 8 --- 8. --- 8.000 
 --- 0008 --- 0008. --- 0008.000 
 --- 0 --- 00000 --- 0. --- 000.

 --- 23456000 --- 23456000 --- 23456000 
 --- 23456000 --- 23456000 --- 23456000 
 --- 10000 --- 10000 --- 10000 
 --- 10000 --- 10000 --- 10000 
 --- 24 --- 24 --- 24 
 --- 24 --- 24 --- 24 
 --- 8 --- 8 --- 8 
 --- 8 --- 8 --- 8 
 --- 0 --- 0 --- 0 --- 0

---------------------------------------------------------------

0.0 --- 0.000 --- 000.0 --- 000.000 --- .000000 --- .0

0 --- 0 --- 0 --- 0 --- 0 --- 0

---------------------------------------------------------------

.00023456 --- .00023456000 --- .00503 --- .00503000 
 --- .068 --- .0680000 --- .8 --- .8000 
 --- .123456123456 --- .123456123456000 
 --- .657 --- .657000 --- .45 --- .4500000 --- .7 --- .70000

0.00023456 --- 0.00023456 --- 0.00503 --- 0.00503 
 --- 0.068 --- 0.068 --- 0.8 --- 0.8 
 --- 0.123456123456 --- 0.123456123456 
 --- 0.657 --- 0.657 --- 0.45 --- 0.45 --- 0.7 --- 0.7

---------------------------------------------------------------

0.0000023230000 --- 000.0000023230000 
 --- 0.0081000 --- 0000.0081000 
 --- 0.059000 --- 0000.059000 
 --- 0.78987400000 --- 00000.78987400000 
 --- 0.4400000 --- 00000.4400000 
 --- 0.5000 --- 0000.5000 
 --- 0.90 --- 000.90 --- 0.7 --- 000.7 

0.000002323 --- 0.000002323 
 --- 0.0081 --- 0.0081 
 --- 0.059 --- 0.059 
 --- 0.789874 --- 0.789874 
 --- 0.44 --- 0.44 
 --- 0.5 --- 0.5 
 --- 0.9 --- 0.9 --- 0.7 --- 0.7 

---------------------------------------------------------------

2.6 --- 00002.6 --- 00002.60000 
 --- 4.71 --- 0004.71 --- 0004.7100 
 --- 23.49 --- 00023.49 --- 00023.490000 
 --- 103.45 --- 0000103.45 --- 0000103.45000 
 --- 10003.45067 --- 000010003.45067 --- 000010003.4506700 
 --- 15000.0012 --- 000015000.0012 --- 000015000.0012000 
 --- 78000.89 --- 000078000.89 --- 000078000.89000

2.6 --- 2.6 --- 2.6 
 --- 4.71 --- 4.71 --- 4.71 
 --- 23.49 --- 23.49 --- 23.49 
 --- 103.45 --- 103.45 --- 103.45 
 --- 10003.45067 --- 10003.45067 --- 10003.45067 
 --- 15000.0012 --- 15000.0012 --- 15000.0012 
 --- 78000.89 --- 78000.89 --- 78000.89

---------------------------------------------------------------

.0457e10 --- .0457000e10 
 --- 0.782e10 --- 0000.782e10 --- 0000.7820000e10 
 --- 1.23E2 --- 0001.23E2 --- 0001.2300000E2 
 --- 1.46e10 --- 0001.46e10 --- 0001.4600000e10 
 --- 1.077e-456 --- 0001.077e-456 --- 0001.077000e-456 
 --- 1.069e10 --- 0001.069e10 --- 0001.069000e10 
 --- 105040.03e10 --- 000105040.03e10 --- 105040.03e10

0.0457e10 --- 0.0457e10 
 --- 0.782e10 --- 0.782e10 --- 0.782e10 
 --- 1.23E2 --- 1.23E2 --- 1.23E2 
 --- 1.46e10 --- 1.46e10 --- 1.46e10 
 --- 1.077e-456 --- 1.077e-456 --- 1.077e-456 
 --- 1.069e10 --- 1.069e10 --- 1.069e10 
 --- 105040.03e10 --- 105040.03e10 --- 105040.03e10

---------------------------------------------------------------

..18000 --- 25..00 --- 36...77 --- 2..8 
 --- 3.8..9 --- .12500. --- 12.51.400

..18000 --- 25..00 --- 36...77 --- 2..8 
 --- 3.8..9 --- .12500. --- 12.51.400

---------------------------------------------------------------
```

.

Consequently, the regex can also been used to merely find all the numbers in a string, without removing the zeros if not wished.

.

**PS:** see more in my other answer that explains the regex and its functionning

Comment: @eyquem: "10000" produces "1" **FAIL**

Comment: @John Machin By chance, yo are here. I will muck around the problem

Comment: @eyquem: "10000.000" also produces "1". "muck around" is an intransitive verb. Transitive example: "You have mucked up the solution."

Comment: @eyquem: `'.0000'` produces `'.'`

Comment: @John Machin Yes, ``'.0000'`` produces ``'.'`` , because the program changes numbers like ``'.657000'`` to ``'.657'`` . I wanted to correct this particular result, because it's a shortcoming for ``'.0000'`` and it isn't good-looking for ``'.657'``, I would prefer ``'0.657'`` too. The code gives also another wrong result: ``'000078000'`` is changed to ``'78'``

Comment: @John Machin I tried to correct these two sorts of problems. For the first one, a solution with a regex can't make a zero to appear before a dot if there is no zero at this position in the analysed string; so, to treat cases such as '.657000' , I am obliged to use a replacement function. It isn't a difficult task to rewrite the treatment with a repl function, it's even easier. But since I give me the supplementary constraint to eliminate the zeros in front of integers (that I excluded of treatment until now), that gives a sort of heavy function.

Comment: @John Machin So I tried to make the replacement function as short as possible by polishing the regex pattern , but I stumbled across a last tiny difficulty. As I have no more time to end the polishing, and I muck about the problem, I prefer to postpone my correction. But there's a regex solution, that's sure.

Answer (score 1):

Script:

```
def tidy_float(s):
    """Return tidied float representation.
    Remove superflous leading/trailing zero digits.
    Remove '.' if value is an integer.
    Return '****' if float(s) fails.
    """
    # float?
    try:
        f = float(s)
    except ValueError:
        return '****'
    # int?
    try:
        i = int(s)
        return str(i)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    # scientific notation?
    if 'e' in s or 'E' in s:
        t = s.lstrip('0')
        if t.startswith('.'): t = '0' + t
        return t
    # float with integral value (includes zero)?
    i = int(f)
    if i == f:
        return str(i)
    assert '.' in s
    t = s.strip('0')
    if t.startswith('.'): t = '0' + t
    if t.endswith('.'): t += '0'
    return t

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Each line has test string followed by expected output
    tests = """
    0.000 0
    0 0
    0000 0
    0.4000 0.4
    0.0081000 0.0081
    103.45 103.45
    103.4506700 103.45067
    14500.0012 14500.0012
    478000.89 478000.89
    993.59.18 ****
    12.5831.400 ****
    .458 0.458
    .48587000 0.48587
    .0000 0
    10000 10000
    10000.000 10000
    -10000 -10000
    -10000.000 -10000
    1.23e2 1.23e2
    1.23e10 1.23e10
    .123e10 0.123e10
     """.splitlines()

    for test in tests:
        x = test.split()
        if not x: continue
        data, expected = x
        actual = tidy_float(data)
        print "data=%r exp=%r act=%r %s" % (
            data, expected, actual, ["**FAIL**", ""][actual == expected])
```

Output (Python 2.7.1):

```
data='0.000' exp='0' act='0'
data='0' exp='0' act='0'
data='0000' exp='0' act='0'
data='0.4000' exp='0.4' act='0.4'
data='0.0081000' exp='0.0081' act='0.0081'
data='103.45' exp='103.45' act='103.45'
data='103.4506700' exp='103.45067' act='103.45067'
data='14500.0012' exp='14500.0012' act='14500.0012'
data='478000.89' exp='478000.89' act='478000.89'
data='993.59.18' exp='****' act='****'
data='12.5831.400' exp='****' act='****'
data='.458' exp='0.458' act='0.458'
data='.48587000' exp='0.48587' act='0.48587'
data='.0000' exp='0' act='0'
data='10000' exp='10000' act='10000'
data='10000.000' exp='10000' act='10000'
data='-10000' exp='-10000' act='-10000'
data='-10000.000' exp='-10000' act='-10000'
data='1.23e2' exp='1.23e2' act='1.23e2'
data='1.23e10' exp='1.23e10' act='1.23e10'
data='.123e10' exp='0.123e10' act='0.123e10'
```

Comment: You'll see in the comparison in my EDIT 2 that ``tidy_float()`` returns ``0.0457000e10`` for **.0457000e10** , returns ``1.077000e-456`` for **0001.077000e-456**, etc

Answer (score 1):

### ADDITION TO THE EDIT 2 of my other answer

(All was to long to be in only one post)

The pattern of the regex defines 4 sub-patterns, each one matching with a certain type of numbers. Each time the regex matches with a part of a string, there is only one of the sub-patterns that matches, hence the possibility to use **mat.lastindex** in the replacement function. The following code shows the matchings of the sub-pattern against various numbers:

```
import re
def float_show(ch,
               regx = re.compile(
                   '(?<![\d.])'
                   '0*' # potentiel heading zeros
                   '(?:'
                   '(\d+)\.?' # INTEGERS :
                              # ~ pure integers non-0 or 0
                              #   000450 , 136000 , 87 , 000 , 0
                              # ~ integer part non-0 + '.'
                              #   0044. , 4100.
                              # ~ integer part 0 + '.'
                              #   000. , 0. 
                              # ~ integer part non-0 + '.' + fractional part 0:
                              #   000570.00 , 193.0 , 3.000

                   '|\.(0)' # SPECIAL CASE, 0 WITH FRACTIONAL PART :
                            # ~ integer part 0 + compulsory fractional part 0:
                            #   000.0, 0.000 , .0 , .00000

                   '|(\.\d+?)' # FLOATING POINT NUMBER
                               # ~ with integer part 0:
                               #   000.0890 , 0.52 , 0.1 , .077000 , .1400 , .0006010

                   '|(\d+\.\d+?)' # FLOATING POINT NUMBER
                                  # ~ with integer part non-0:
                                  #   0024000.013000 , 145.0235 , 3.00058
                   ')'
                   '0*' # potential tailing zeros
                   '(?![\d.])'),
               repl = lambda mat: mat.group(mat.lastindex)
                                  if mat.lastindex!=3
                                  else '0' + mat.group(3)  ):
    mat = regx.search(ch)
    if mat:
        return (ch,regx.sub(repl,ch),repr(mat.groups()))
    else:
        return (ch,'No match','No groups')


numbers = ['23456000', '23456000.', '23456000.000',
           '00023456000', '000023456000.', '000023456000.000',
           '10000', '10000.', '10000.000',
           '00010000', '00010000.', '00010000.000',
           '24', '24.', '24.000',
           '00024', '00024.', '00024.000',
           '8', '8.', '8.000',
           '0008', '0008.', '0008.000',
           '0', '00000', '0.', '000.',
           '\n',
           '0.0', '0.000', '000.0', '000.000', '.000000', '.0',
           '\n',
           '.00023456', '.00023456000', '.00503', '.00503000',
           '.068', '.0680000', '.8', '.8000',
           '.123456123456', '.123456123456000',
           '.657', '.657000', '.45', '.4500000', '.7', '.70000',
           '\n',
           '0.0000023230000', '000.0000023230000',
           '0.0081000', '0000.0081000',
           '0.059000', '0000.059000',
           '0.78987400000', '00000.78987400000',
           '0.4400000', '00000.4400000',
           '0.5000', '0000.5000',
           '0.90', '000.90', '0.7', '000.7',
           '\n',
           '2.6', '00002.6', '00002.60000',
           '4.71', '0004.71', '0004.7100',
           '23.49', '00023.49', '00023.490000',
           '103.45', '0000103.45', '0000103.45000',
           '10003.45067', '000010003.45067', '000010003.4506700',
           '15000.0012', '000015000.0012', '000015000.0012000',
           '78000.89', '000078000.89', '000078000.89000',
           '\n',
           '.0457e10', '.0457000e10',
           '0.782e10', '0000.782e10', '0000.7820000e10',
           '1.23E2', '0001.23E2', '0001.2300000E2',
           '1.46e10', '0001.46e10', '0001.4600000e10',
           '1.077e-456', '0001.077e-456', '0001.077000e-456',
           '1.069e10', '0001.069e10', '0001.069000e10',
           '105040.03e10', '000105040.03e10', '105040.0300e10',
           '\n',
           '..18000', '25..00',  '36...77', '2..8',
           '3.8..9', '.12500.', '12.51.400' ]

pat = '%20s  %-16s %s'
li = [pat % ('tested number ',' shaved float',' regx.search(number).groups()')]
li.extend(pat % float_show(ch) if ch!='\n' else '\n' for ch in numbers)
print '\n'.join(li)
```

demonstrates

```
      tested number    shaved float     regx.search(number).groups()
            23456000  23456000         ('23456000', None, None, None)
           23456000.  23456000         ('23456000', None, None, None)
        23456000.000  23456000         ('23456000', None, None, None)
         00023456000  23456000         ('23456000', None, None, None)
       000023456000.  23456000         ('23456000', None, None, None)
    000023456000.000  23456000         ('23456000', None, None, None)
               10000  10000            ('10000', None, None, None)
              10000.  10000            ('10000', None, None, None)
           10000.000  10000            ('10000', None, None, None)
            00010000  10000            ('10000', None, None, None)
           00010000.  10000            ('10000', None, None, None)
        00010000.000  10000            ('10000', None, None, None)
                  24  24               ('24', None, None, None)
                 24.  24               ('24', None, None, None)
              24.000  24               ('24', None, None, None)
               00024  24               ('24', None, None, None)
              00024.  24               ('24', None, None, None)
           00024.000  24               ('24', None, None, None)
                   8  8                ('8', None, None, None)
                  8.  8                ('8', None, None, None)
               8.000  8                ('8', None, None, None)
                0008  8                ('8', None, None, None)
               0008.  8                ('8', None, None, None)
            0008.000  8                ('8', None, None, None)
                   0  0                ('0', None, None, None)
               00000  0                ('0', None, None, None)
                  0.  0                ('0', None, None, None)
                000.  0                ('0', None, None, None)


                 0.0  0                (None, '0', None, None)
               0.000  0                (None, '0', None, None)
               000.0  0                (None, '0', None, None)
             000.000  0                (None, '0', None, None)
             .000000  0                (None, '0', None, None)
                  .0  0                (None, '0', None, None)


           .00023456  0.00023456       (None, None, '.00023456', None)
        .00023456000  0.00023456       (None, None, '.00023456', None)
              .00503  0.00503          (None, None, '.00503', None)
           .00503000  0.00503          (None, None, '.00503', None)
                .068  0.068            (None, None, '.068', None)
            .0680000  0.068            (None, None, '.068', None)
                  .8  0.8              (None, None, '.8', None)
               .8000  0.8              (None, None, '.8', None)
       .123456123456  0.123456123456   (None, None, '.123456123456', None)
    .123456123456000  0.123456123456   (None, None, '.123456123456', None)
                .657  0.657            (None, None, '.657', None)
             .657000  0.657            (None, None, '.657', None)
                 .45  0.45             (None, None, '.45', None)
            .4500000  0.45             (None, None, '.45', None)
                  .7  0.7              (None, None, '.7', None)
              .70000  0.7              (None, None, '.7', None)


     0.0000023230000  0.000002323      (None, None, '.000002323', None)
   000.0000023230000  0.000002323      (None, None, '.000002323', None)
           0.0081000  0.0081           (None, None, '.0081', None)
        0000.0081000  0.0081           (None, None, '.0081', None)
            0.059000  0.059            (None, None, '.059', None)
         0000.059000  0.059            (None, None, '.059', None)
       0.78987400000  0.789874         (None, None, '.789874', None)
   00000.78987400000  0.789874         (None, None, '.789874', None)
           0.4400000  0.44             (None, None, '.44', None)
       00000.4400000  0.44             (None, None, '.44', None)
              0.5000  0.5              (None, None, '.5', None)
           0000.5000  0.5              (None, None, '.5', None)
                0.90  0.9              (None, None, '.9', None)
              000.90  0.9              (None, None, '.9', None)
                 0.7  0.7              (None, None, '.7', None)
               000.7  0.7              (None, None, '.7', None)


                 2.6  2.6              (None, None, None, '2.6')
             00002.6  2.6              (None, None, None, '2.6')
         00002.60000  2.6              (None, None, None, '2.6')
                4.71  4.71             (None, None, None, '4.71')
             0004.71  4.71             (None, None, None, '4.71')
           0004.7100  4.71             (None, None, None, '4.71')
               23.49  23.49            (None, None, None, '23.49')
            00023.49  23.49            (None, None, None, '23.49')
        00023.490000  23.49            (None, None, None, '23.49')
              103.45  103.45           (None, None, None, '103.45')
          0000103.45  103.45           (None, None, None, '103.45')
       0000103.45000  103.45           (None, None, None, '103.45')
         10003.45067  10003.45067      (None, None, None, '10003.45067')
     000010003.45067  10003.45067      (None, None, None, '10003.45067')
   000010003.4506700  10003.45067      (None, None, None, '10003.45067')
          15000.0012  15000.0012       (None, None, None, '15000.0012')
      000015000.0012  15000.0012       (None, None, None, '15000.0012')
   000015000.0012000  15000.0012       (None, None, None, '15000.0012')
            78000.89  78000.89         (None, None, None, '78000.89')
        000078000.89  78000.89         (None, None, None, '78000.89')
     000078000.89000  78000.89         (None, None, None, '78000.89')


            .0457e10  0.0457e10        (None, None, '.0457', None)
         .0457000e10  0.0457e10        (None, None, '.0457', None)
            0.782e10  0.782e10         (None, None, '.782', None)
         0000.782e10  0.782e10         (None, None, '.782', None)
     0000.7820000e10  0.782e10         (None, None, '.782', None)
              1.23E2  1.23E2           (None, None, None, '1.23')
           0001.23E2  1.23E2           (None, None, None, '1.23')
      0001.2300000E2  1.23E2           (None, None, None, '1.23')
             1.46e10  1.46e10          (None, None, None, '1.46')
          0001.46e10  1.46e10          (None, None, None, '1.46')
     0001.4600000e10  1.46e10          (None, None, None, '1.46')
          1.077e-456  1.077e-456       (None, None, None, '1.077')
       0001.077e-456  1.077e-456       (None, None, None, '1.077')
    0001.077000e-456  1.077e-456       (None, None, None, '1.077')
            1.069e10  1.069e10         (None, None, None, '1.069')
         0001.069e10  1.069e10         (None, None, None, '1.069')
      0001.069000e10  1.069e10         (None, None, None, '1.069')
        105040.03e10  105040.03e10     (None, None, None, '105040.03')
     000105040.03e10  105040.03e10     (None, None, None, '105040.03')
      105040.0300e10  105040.03e10     (None, None, None, '105040.03')


             ..18000  No match         No groups
              25..00  No match         No groups
             36...77  No match         No groups
                2..8  No match         No groups
              3.8..9  No match         No groups
             .12500.  No match         No groups
           12.51.400  No match         No groups
```