# java: use regular expression to extract a number in a string

Tags: java, regex, matching

I have a string of format "[232]......." I want to extract the 232 out of the string, I did this

```
public static int getNumber(String str) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[([0-9]+)\\]");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    int number = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        number = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group());
    }
    return number;
}
```

but it doesn't work, I got the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[232]"
```

Anyone knows how could I solve this problem, and if there is a more efficient way for me to do this kind of pattern matching in java?

Comment: BoltClock has answered your question, for more info on extracting numbers take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917082/regular-expression-to-match-numbers-with-or-without-commas-and-decimals-in-text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`group()` without any parameters returns the entire match (equivalent to `group(0)`). That includes the square brackets that you've specified in your regex.

To extract the number, pass `1` to return only the first capture group within your regex (the `([0-9]+)`):

```
number = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
```