# Regular expression : match either of two conditions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, angularjs-ng-pattern

Hi I don't know much about regular expression. But I need it in form validation using angularJs.

Below is the requirement

The input box should accept only if either

**(1) first 2 letters alpha  + 6 numeric**

**or**

**(2) 8 numeric**

Below are some correct Inputs :-

(1)SH123456
(2)12345678 
(3)sd456565

I tried `data-ng-pattern="/(^([a-zA-Z]){2}([0-9]){6})|([0-9]*)?$/"` , Its working fine for both the above condition but still it is accepting strings like S2D3E4F5 and may be many other combination as well.

What I am doing wrong I am not able to find it out.

Any help is appreciable !!!

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In a regular expression, match one thing or another, or both](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351990/in-a-regular-expression-match-one-thing-or-another-or-both)

Comment: @DavidR No, this is not a duplicate of that. It’s an anchoring problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your regex, the two alternative branches are anchored separately:

- `(^([a-zA-Z]){2}([0-9]){6})` - 2 letters and 6 digits at the start of the string
- `|` - or
- `([0-9]*)?$` - optional zero or more digits at the end of  the string

You need to adjust the boundaries of the group:

```
data-ng-pattern="/^([a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}|[0-9]{8})?$/"
                   ^                         ^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kU6aY2/2).

Now, the pattern will match:

- `^` - start of string
- `(` - start of the grouping:

  - `[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}` - 2 letters and 6 digits
  - `|` - or
  - `[0-9]{8}` - 8 digits
- `)?` - end of the grouping and `?` quantifier makes it match 1 or 0 times (optional)
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: @revo: If someone downvotes your answers, probably there is something wrong with them. I did not express any concern, I only asked for a "constructive critique". Plain downvotes do not add value when the answer given is detailed, working and helpful.

Comment: In a normal case that's right but not times when **you** receive a down-vote. For sure I'll do what I said if I see the same behavior another time.

Comment: @revo Please do it now.

Comment: I'll do it certainly but in a more appropriate time when I'm sure my complaint is going to take into account.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this [DEMO LINK HERE](https://regex101.com/r/kU6aY2/3)

```
^(([a-zA-Z]{2}|[0-9]{2})[0-9]{6})?$
```

It will accept:

1. ab123456
2. 12345678
3. aa441236
4. aw222222

Comment: It is semantically the same as mine, so it will also work. The formal difference is just 1 nested capturing group is used here while mine has no nested groups. Both have similar performance.

Comment: 6 numeric values are common for both case. that's why I used a common part for 6 numeric values. and there are many ways to write regular expression. :)

Comment: Equivalent to `^([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[0-9]{6})?$`, it seems.

Comment: No. your expression will also except a1234567. But its need First 2 letters alpha + 6  @jensgram