# In a regular expression, capture one thing, or another, or both

Tags: python, regex

Here is a piece of text I have :

```
G1   13.00
G1    3.00
      0.00
       27C
```

I am trying to use regex to capture one group which is a alpha-numeric code (G1 or 27C) or another group which is a float (xx.xx), or both of them.

For this example, I want this specific return:

```
(G1,13.00)
(G1,3.00)
(,0.00)
(27C,)
```

this is the closest solution I have :

```
\(?:(\w+) +(\d+\.\d+))|(?: +(\d+\.\d+))|(?: +(\w+))\
```

The problem with this solution is that the last 2 rows values are captured in the 3rd and a 4th group:

```
(G1,13.00,,)
(G1,3.00,,)
(,,0.00,)
(,,,27C)
```

Any ideas on how to solve it ?

I have found this question which is close : [In a regular expression, match one thing or another, or both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351990/in-a-regular-expression-match-one-thing-or-another-or-both) but it answers how to *match* and not to *capture*.

Comment: With PyPi regex module, you could use `(?|(\w+) +(\d+\.\d+)| +(\d+\.\d+)| +(\w+))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need same patterns to be matched by same capturing groups.

This will return always 2 groups:

```
(\w+)? *\b(\d+\.\d+)?
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iPfvGW/2)

EDIT: if you want no empty match, try this:

```
(?=\w)(\w+(?=$|\s))? *\b(\d+\.\d+)?
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iPfvGW/5)

Comment: thanks but It matches with 0 characters and then I give me too much matches.

Comment: @GregOizo I edited the answer, now let me check if the regex is simplifiable

Comment: Well, I think it is ok