# In a regular expression, match one thing or another, or both while maintaining group names

Tags: python, regex

I wish to expand on the discussion on the following question

[In a regular expression, match one thing or another, or both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351990/in-a-regular-expression-match-one-thing-or-another-or-both)

with a new condition that I want to name the groups consistently. Something like this -

`((?P<A>A)|(?P<B>B)) | ((?P<A>A)(?P<B>B))`

which triggers `re.error: redefinition of group name ...` in Python.

**Additional info in case it helps**: In my specific application, A is a date and B is a time. Basically I want to allow users to enter a date, or a time, or a date followed by a time (which is why A?B? would not work for me as I do not want it empty).

The group name feature of regex turns out to be very handy when it comes to parsing the date and/or time info to datetime objects and functionalities. This is why I want to be able to keep naming A A and B B even when the pattern repeats. This makes the accepted solution in the cited discussion not work for me.

**Edit**: Yes, I agree that repeating a pattern is not a good idea in the first place especially when date and time are already messy.

Comment: What about `AB?` This way `A` is always present and `B` is optional

Comment: I need both optional, but at least one.

Comment: I still don't think repeating the pattern is a good idea, consider using a lookahead to exclude empty cases such as [`(?!$)((?P<A>A)?(?P<B>B)?)`](https://regex101.com/r/fHzEga/1)

Comment: Or assert at least a single non whitespace character `(?=\S)((?P<A>A)?(?P<B>B)?)` See https://regex101.com/r/bn8vnL/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird I think this is the perfect solution for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the possibility to match either one of the groups or both groups without matching an empty string, you can assert a non whitespace char to the right of the current position:

```
(?=\S)((?P<A>A)?(?P<B>B)?)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bn8vnL/1).