# Matching both \d and \. in a regular expression

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to match any combination of float numbers with a regular expression in VBA inside of Microsoft Word.

Example:

```
<text="">
<text="1">
<text="2">
<text="3">
<text="3.5">
<text="4">
<text="44">
```

I've tried the following patterns:

```
regex.Pattern = "<text=" & Chr(34) & "\d*\.*\d*" & Chr(34) & ">"
regex.Pattern = "<text=" & Chr(34) & "[\d\.]*" & Chr(34) & ">"
```

What's interesting is neither of these patterns will match the 44 either.

Comment: fyi: `*` will match "0 or more". If you want ONLY elements with numbers, then use `+` (1 or more).

Comment: Yes, I'm aware, it's what I want, I also want to handle <text="">

Comment: I don't know about word and VBA in perl i'd do something like this: "(\d+(\.\d+)?)?"

Comment: Thanks, but vba is not pcre.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917082/regular-expression-to-match-numbers-with-or-without-commas-and-decimals-in-text) and its answers should tell you all you need to know, and more.

Answer (score 0):

from the [regex tester](http://www.regextester.com/) site,

Positive Integers --- `^\d+$`
Negative Integers --- `^-\d+$`
Integer --- `^-{0,1}\d+$`
Positive Number --- `^\d*\.{0,1}\d+$`
Negative Number --- `^-\d*\.{0,1}\d+$`
Positive Number or Negative Number - `^-{0,1}\d*\.{0,1}\d+$`

to test for the empty result being valid, and assuming all positive numbers, you would end up with

```
regex.Pattern = "<text=" & Chr(34) & "\d*\.{0,1}\d*" & Chr(34) & ">"
```

Comment: You'll notice this isn't different from my pattern other than you say 0 or 1 decimals, and I allow any. Also, doesn't work for me still.

Comment: a float will only have 0 or 1 decimals. 1.1.1 is not a valid number

Comment: Additionally, you're very off base with your use of ^ and $, as my sample text shows it's clearly not the beginning or end of line.

Comment: fixed example. the $ and ^ were from me testing the number part only

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down. A floating point number has two parts, integral and decimal. There are some choices on the format:

Here is pattern for a pretty common notation:

```
regex.Pattern = "<text=" & Chr(34) & "(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)?" & Chr(34) & ">"
```

Some choices:

- Do you want to support omitting the integral part? (e.g. '.001')
  Use `*` instead of `+` in the first number match: `(-?\d*(\.\d+)?)?`
- Do you want to support leading zeros? (e.g. 000.)
  This is gonna be more tricky :)
- Do you want to support decimal point without decimal part? (e.g. '12.')
  Then add `?` after the decimal point match: `(-?\d*(\.?\d+)?)?`
- Is the decimal part mandatory?
  Remove the very last `?`: `(-?\d*(\.?\d+))?`