# RegularExpression-ValidationExpression on validating aspxtextbox with decimal mask

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

Hi all this is my aspxtextbox design, what I did is I have taken mask along with regular expression validation as follows

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtBalance" runat="server" Width="150">
                            <MaskSettings Mask="<0..999999999999g>.<00..99>" IncludeLiterals="DecimalSymbol" />
                            <ValidationSettings RegularExpression-ValidationExpression="^(?:\d{1,14}|\d{1,11}\.\d\d)$">
                            </ValidationSettings>
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

[image]

But this is firing error what I need is I need to validate this input `111,111,111,111.11` which is a maximum input as per my requirement

Answer (score 0):

it is failing because of two reasons the main one is your regex will only accept a decimal place upto the eleventh character and secondly you arent matching the commmas you are putting in to separate your number up.

take a look at this[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917082/regular-expression-to-match-numbers-with-or-without-commas-and-decimals-in-text) to find a regex that would do what your after