# Regex search to extract float from string. Python

Tags: python, regex, search, find

```
import re

sequence = 'i have -0.03 dollars in my hand'

m = re.search('(have )(-\w[.]+)( dollars\w+)',sequence)

print m.group(0)
print m.group(1)
print m.group(2)
```

Looking for a way to extract text between two occurrences.  In this case, the format is 'i have ' followed by - floats and then followed by ' dollars\w+'

How  do i use re.search to extract this float ? 
Why don't the groups work this way ? I know there's something I can tweak to get it to work with these groups.  any help would be greatly appreciated

I thought I could use groups with paranthesis but  i got an eror

Comment: How can you have -0.03 dollars in your hand? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-\w[.]+` does not match `-0.03` because `[.]` matches `.` literally because `.` is inside the `[...]`.

`\w` after `dollars` also prevent the pattern to match the `sequence`. There no word character after `dollars`.

Use `(-?\d+\.\d+)` as pattern:

```
import re

sequence = 'i have -0.03 dollars in my hand'

m = re.search(r'(have )(-?\d+\.\d+)( dollars)', sequence)

print m.group(1) # captured group start from `1`.
print m.group(2) 
print m.group(3)
```

BTW, captured group numbers start from `1`. (`group(0)` returns entire matched string)

Comment: @draconisthe0ry, `-?` make `-` optional because `<RE>?` match 0 or 1 occurrence of `RE`.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex doesn't match for several reasons:

- it always requires a `-` (OK in this case, questionable in general)
- it requires exactly one digit before the `.` (and it even allows non-digits like `A`).
- it allows any number of dots, but no more digits after the dots.
- it requires one or more alphanumerics immediately after `dollars`.

So it would match `"I have -X.... dollarsFOO in my hand"` but not `"I have 0.10 dollars in my hand"`.

Also, there is no use in putting fixed texts into capturing parentheses.

```
m = re.search(r'\bhave (-?\d+\.\d+) dollars\b', sequence)
```

would make much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been asked in many formulations before. You're looking for a regular expression that will find a number. Since number formats may include decimals, commas, exponents, plus/minus signs, and leading zeros, you'll need a robust regular expression. Fortunately, this regular expression has already been written for you.

See [How to extract a floating number from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703390/how-to-extract-a-floating-number-from-a-string-in-python/18237992#18237992) and [Regular expression to match numbers with or without commas and decimals in text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917082/regular-expression-to-match-numbers-with-or-without-commas-and-decimals-in-text/5929469#5929469)