# Strip a list item for extracting a specific value in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list, which was produced as output of a python script in the following format:

```
[' (* 100.856 UnitA', ') [ 98.0%]',
 ' (* 100.598 UnitB', ') [ 98.0%]', 
 ' (*  98.193 UnitC', ') [ 25.6%]']
```

Now, I am interested to put the floating point values in every list item to a new list for further processing in a python script. Is there a way (an in-built python function maybe) I can strip the floating point content alone to a new list? In the above example my desired output would be like :

```
[100.856,98.0,100.598,98.0,98.193,25.6]
```

If not an in-built function, any other alternate way I can achieve this?

Comment: This could be done simply in a loop or a list comprehension. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried using extend. Realized won't work. New to python. So, wanted to explore the options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a regex pattern from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21156273/regex-search-to-extract-float-from-string-python) will extract the floats and cast to float as desired:

```
In [153]:
l=[' (* 100.856 UnitA', ') [ 98.0%]',
 ' (* 100.598 UnitB', ') [ 98.0%]', 
 ' (*  98.193 UnitC', ') [ 25.6%]']
import re
[float(re.findall(r'(-?\d+\.\d+)',x)[0]) for x in l]

Out[153]:
[100.856, 98.0, 100.598, 98.0, 98.193, 25.6]
```

So the tricky thing here is that you need to search for digits `\d` but also search for the decimal point and trailing digits