# java Regex Pattern for decimals and integers

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regex in Java  to detect a decimal or a integer from a given text.

I have used the following pattern.

```
Pattern.compile("(\\d*\\.*?\\d*)%");
```

My intention is match occurences like 5%,0.5%,.5%,5.0%.

Is my pattern sufficient for all the matches ?

Comment: One good way to find out: write a good unit test/tests for it. :)

Comment: You pattern allows for more than one decimal point

Comment: This may help

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308122/simple-regular-expression-for-a-decimal-with-a-precision-of-2

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917082/regular-expression-to-match-numbers-with-or-without-commas-and-decimals-in-text