# Get documents whose text field contains only a number value in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Does there exist any query or filter that gives me only the documents where specific text field contains only a number value?

I have a text field (called "guess", feel free to use another name) that contain only one number in most cases ("guess":"333" for example, and not "guess":"34 34")  or free text ("guess":"blah blah blah" for example, and "guess":"34 34" is free text too).

Best Regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [Regexp Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/query-dsl-regexp-filter.html) (or Query)

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
                "regexp":{
                    "guess": "[0-9]*"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to match more complex number formats, reference [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917082/regular-expression-to-match-numbers-with-or-without-commas-and-decimals-in-text)

Comment: If you have the luxury of discarding records with `guess` values that are not a single number, define a numeric [core type mapping property](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#number) for this field.   (Or you can `ignore_malformed` so that the records with bad `guess` values are simply not searched)

Comment: i try by {
   "filtered": {
        "query": {
           "bool":{"must":[{"range":{"document.guess":{"from":"99999"}}},{"term":{"document.status":"active"}}]}
},
        "filter": {
         "regexp":{
      "document.guess": "[0-9]*"
            }
        }
    }
,"from":0,"size":1,"sort":[],"facets":{}
}

Comment: but i get : an exception: {
"error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[yJYl31UrQ1qst3pCIfsZ_Q][mx][0]: RemoteTransportException[[Savage Steel][inet[/<iphere>:9300]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[mx][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"filtered":{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"document.guess":{"from":"99999"}}},{"term":{"document.status":"active"}}],"must_not":[],"should":[]}},"filter":{"regexp":{"document.guess":"[0-9]*"}}},"from":.....

Comment: I only posted the inner part of the query DSL.  Just updated the post to include the {"query": {...}} wrapper.

Comment: I will try it by java api I've lucky with java api, maybe i'm useless with jsons : )

Comment: Thanks for the help peterdm