# RegEx to match anything BUT decimal numbers with percent symbol

Tags: php, regex

I'm terrible at RegEx.  Can anyone show a regex to use if I want to check a string for anything BUT digits 0-9, decimal point and percent sign?

I've tried this...

```
if (preg_match('/[^0-9.]+%/i',  $string)) {
     echo 'invalid';
}
```

but it's not working correctly.  I have a input field which asks a user what the tax rate should be, and this is going to verify they have entered a VALID tax rate.  I want them to enter it like "5.2%" rather than in decimal, and I will do the math on the back-end.

A VALID match would be "6%" or "5.2%" etc.
A INVALID match would be "2" or "0.05" or "A"

Comment: Why is the percent outside the brackets?

Comment: why the down votes?  is this not an "acceptable" question?

Comment: You don't need `+` if you're just testing for existence of something. A single character match is enough.

Comment: @Barmar - I tried inside the brackets but it didn't seem to work there either

Comment: Then you haven't explained what you want, because that should fix it.

Comment: Does the match have to be the whole string? Is `10 is 5% of 50` valid?

Comment: @Barmar - updated my question to give more insight into what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for a valid match, then invert it in the test:

```
if (!preg_match('/[\d.]%/', $string) {
    echo 'invalid';
}
```

But since this is supposed to test the whole string, not just look for a percentage anywhere in it, you need to anchor it:

```
if (!preg_match('/^[\d.]+%$/', $string) {
    echo 'invalid';
}
```

Note that this will allow something like `.%`. You probably should use something like [Regular expression to match numbers with or without commas and decimals in text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917082/regular-expression-to-match-numbers-with-or-without-commas-and-decimals-in-text?noredirect=1&lq=1) to match the number part.

Comment: thank you - will accept as correct as soon as it lets me.

Comment: @anubhava No, that's why I suggested replacing `[\d.]` with the answer in that other question, because it should be invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You can match valid input and reverse your if condition:

```
if (preg_match('/\b\d*\.?\d+%/',  $string) === FALSE) {
     echo 'invalid';
}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/crvKEs/1)

Comment: thank you!!!  Your post was very helpful but to be fair Barmar's suggestion works too and he was a minute sooner.  Thank you though!

Comment: Of course, it is your prerogative to mark any answer but just for the fact, my answer was 5 sec faster :)

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't realize that.  How do I see the exact timestamp?

Comment: Just the mouse over "answered ... ago" text below the answers

Comment: I see it now...I had no idea.  Will be sure to check this in the future thank you!