# How would you write a regex that matches a number with commas for every three digits?

Tags: python, regex

**It must match the following:**

- '42'
- '1,234'
- '6,368,745'

**but not the following:**

- '12,34,567' (which has only two digits between the commas)
- '1234' (which lacks commas)

I wrote following python program in python 3. what am I doing wrong here? It gives AttributeError

```
import re
numRegx = re.compile(r"""^
(\d{1,3}(\,))? # optional first three digits and comma (1,)
((d{3})(\,))*  # optional Second three digits and comma (345,)
\d{3}$         # Last three digits (456)
""", re.VERBOSE)
mo = numRegx.search('1,345,456')
print(mo.group())
```

Comment: `'42'` lacks commas as well, so why you want it? Also our regex doesn't match anything and returns None, that's why you're getting attribute error.

Comment: Yes. I see what's problem(comma is required in my code) with 42 but why does it not work with 1,345,456? @Kasramvd.

Comment: re.VERBOSE will handle it @SiHa

Comment: I think that's because of new-lines but still your regex is not correct.

Comment: @Kasramvd, re.VERBOSE also ignores new-lines. I tried it in single line also.

Comment: In single line without comments it gives me `345,456`.

Comment: Also how you want to handle 42?

Comment: I would handle numbers with less than 4 digits using the last part with `{1,3}`.

Comment: http://www.diveintopython.net/regular_expressions/verbose.html 

From the link: Whitespace is ignored. Spaces, tabs, and carriage returns are not matched as spaces, tabs, and carriage returns. They're not matched at all. (If you want to match a space in a verbose regular expression, you'll need to escape it by putting a backslash in front of it.)
 

why it make the differance @Kasramvd

Comment: So what's you general strategy for matching numbers? please update your question with a comprehensive explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(\d{1,3})(,\d{3})*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/Dy83Jv/1

Answer (score 2):

This Should Work.

Regex:

```
^(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)$
```

JavaScript Code:

```js
const regex = /^(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)$/gm;
const str = `42
1,234
6,368,745
12,34,567`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Input:

```
42
1,234
6,368,745
12,34,567
9999999,123
```

Output:

```
42
1,234
6,368,745
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/oq67pb/2

Comment: This match 9999999,123

Comment: @ChaldaPnuzig fixed my friend :D

Answer (score 0):

The Answer here might be useful for your needs

```
(:?^|\s)(?=.)((?:0|(?:[1-9](?:\d*|\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})*)))?(?:\.\d*[1-9])?)(?!\S)
```

This was the accepted answer to a similar question:

[Regular expression to match numbers with or without commas and decimals in text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917082/regular-expression-to-match-numbers-with-or-without-commas-and-decimals-in-text)