# Regex Extracting Price out of String

Tags: c#, python, regex, vb.net, uipath

I am trying to extract the price from a string, but unable to fully complete the logic.

My String: (2) 1,127.22 abcdfg sdkjf 20,200.01 abcdfg sdfkgj (2) 10.28

What I want to do is:

```
to find all "(2)" in the string and then extract the full price next to it. 

My regex pattern is: "\d+(,\d{1,100})"
```

My pattern only finds 1,127, 20,200 10 in the big string and it also doesn't have the condition of checking if it is next to (2).

I want to get the full price: 1,127.22 and 10.28

EDIT:

Managed to get cents with the regex: \d+(,\d{1,100})(.\d\d?)

Comment: try http://regex101.com to play with regex

Comment: I have been doing that already, I managed to get cents, but unable to get (2) ones. No reason to give -1 since your respond actually wasn't helpful.

Comment: You may use [`\(2\)\s*(\d[\d,.]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/F7PGN0/1) and grab Group 1 value. A more specific pattern can be written as [`\(2\)\s*(\d+(?:,\d+)*\.\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/F7PGN0/2).

Comment: not me down-voting. another good reference for the future: https://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: Sorry, but have you tried my solution? Did any work?

Comment: Yes! Thank you, yours worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [regex](https://regex101.com/r/PQbveh/1) matches one or more digits `\d+` and then in a captured group match a comma and a digit from 1 till 100 times. That matches `1,127` but not `1,127.22`. As you mentioned, the is also no condition of checking if it is next to (2).

This regex could be an option to do it:

[`\(2\)\s(\d+[,.]\d+(?:[.]\d+)?)`](https://regex101.com/r/YA4Gkx/1/)

**Explanation**

- Match (2) `\(2\)`
- Match a whitespace `\s`
- A capturing group `(` (This is where your values will be)
- Match one or more digits, a comma or a dot and one or more digits `\d+[,.]\d+`
- An optional non capturing group which matches a dot followed by on or more digits `(?:[.]\d+)?`
- Close the capturing group

[Output with C#](http://rextester.com/LRZU76541)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
s = "(2) 1,127.22 abcdfg sdkjf 20,200.01 abcdfg sdfkgj (2) 10.28"
vals = re.findall('(?<=\d\)\s)[\d\.,]+', s)
```

Output:

```
['1,127.22', '10.28']
```

If you want a list of floats, rather than strings:

```
vals = list(map(lambda x:float(re.sub(',', '', x)), re.findall('(?<=\d\)\s)[\d\.,]+', s)))
```

Output:

```
[1127.22, 10.28]
```

Answer (score 0):

`(?<=\(2\))\s*((:?^|\s)(?=.)((?:0|(?:[1-9](?:\d*|\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})*)))?(?:\.\d*[1-9])?)(?!\S))`

Borrowed the num seq from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917082/regular-expression-to-match-numbers-with-or-without-commas-and-decimals-in-text)

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET answer without regex. Shows you how to play with strings

```
        Dim SplitStr As String() = New String() {"(2)"}
        Dim mystring As String = "(2) 1,127.22 abcdfg sdkjf 20,200.01 abcdfg sdfkgj (2) 10.28"

        Dim PriceList As New List(Of Decimal)
        For Each xItem In mystring.Split(SplitStr, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            PriceList.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(xItem.Split(New Char() {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)(0)))
        Next
```