# Extract number from string using regular expressions [multiple formatting options]

Tags: regex, numbers

I'm scratching my head trying to come up with a regex that extracts numbers from strings that are differently formatted. For example:

```
'1', '1.1', '1,1', '1,000,000.20', '1.00000020', '1.000.000,20', '10.20001'
```

I currently use the regex `[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?`
and it works well in the majority of the cases except from `1,000,000.20` and `1.000.000,20`.

Do you have any idea how can I tweak the previous regex to work with those examples?

Comment: In your case, you may just capture what is inside single quotes, `'([^']+)'`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917082/regular-expression-to-match-numbers-with-or-without-commas-and-decimals-in-text might be useful. In particular you can use "Commas optional as long as they're consistent" twice (with ',' and '.' exchanged).

Comment: Are you using a programming language here?

Comment: @joanfihu Note that if your texts are clean and numbers  are not following each other (after a comma or dot), you might try something like [`\d[\d.,]*(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?`](https://regex101.com/r/wUPLoo/1). Enclose with word boundaries if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?!\d+,\d+\.\d+,|\d+\.\d+,\d+.)^([+-]?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[.,]\d{3})*)(?:[.,]\d+|[eE][+-]?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[.,]\d{3})*))?)$
```

Perhaps something like this?

This will match all of the ones you stated, plus numbers written in the format `1e10` and `1e-9`.

It will also not match numbers where there are inconsistencies in the comma dot format, i.e `10.234245,214`,`10.234,245.214` or `10,234.245,214`

Also will allow for `+` or `-` at the beginning of these numbers

Check it out on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/WAFUZW/9)