# Match String having a comma in the middle with a regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to try a regex to match my string of this kind like

```
if (cadena.matches("[0-9],[0-9]")){

    Do something} //this being like if the string has numbers before and after the comma
```

Which way can I put this condition? An input example for the match could be `cadena = "2,2345"`

I have tried ".*\d+,\d+.*" and ".*[0-9],[0-9].*" I have tried using my last try with "[0-9]+,[0-9]+" this says any more numbers and seems to work

Using the last one solved my question sorry for the effort.

Comment: Check this out [Regular expression for floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643009/regular-expression-for-floating-point-numbers)
And 
[Regular expression to match numbers with or without commas and decimals in text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917082/regular-expression-to-match-numbers-with-or-without-commas-and-decimals-in-text)

Comment: What have you already tried?  Where did it go wrong?  Because .... `\d+,\d+` sort of comes to mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the method matches(regex) matches the entire string.

You can change your pattern to match the entire string.

```
 if (cadena.matches(".*[0-9],[0-9].*")){
      // Do Something
 }
```

Or you could use find, to find a number comma number anywhere in the string:

```
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9],[0-9]");
 if (pattern.matcher(cadena).find()){
      // Do Something
 }
```

If you wanted to actually use the numbers that matched both sides of the comma in your if block, you can use () to capture groups and refernce them with a Matcher.

```
    String cadena = "2,2345";
    Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+),([0-9]+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern2.matcher(cadena);
    if (matcher.find()){
        System.out.println("Found " + matcher.group(1) + " - " + matcher.group(2));
    }

    // Prints: Found 2 - 2345
```

Comment: The first one I have tried it since using merely ".*[0-9],[0-9].*" will allow a stirng like this asas12,2345

Comment: Will take this onse as the answer with the [0-9]+,[0-9]+ thanx