# PHP Regex amount before € sign ignores decimal

Tags: php, regex

i have the text:

```
  <a href="blahblahblah-dynamic" class="blahblahblah-dynamic" 
  title="blahblahblah-dynamic">2.550,00 €</a>1000 € 900 € 5000 € ......
```

and the expression:

```
#(\d+[\.\,]\d*?)\s?[€]#su
```

that matches:

```
550,00
```

example in: [regexr](https://regexr.com/3s056)

How can I match the whole:
`2.550,00` ?

p.s I dont want to match the others 1000, 900 and numbers without `,` and/or `.`
In other words, I want to match d,d or d.d,d
so the question [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917082/regular-expression-to-match-numbers-with-or-without-commas-and-decimals-in-text), does not cover my case.

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: You could try `#([\d.,]*?)\s?[€]#su`, but this also allows things like `1.00,0 €`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match numbers with or without commas and decimals in text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917082/regular-expression-to-match-numbers-with-or-without-commas-and-decimals-in-text)

Comment: You will need adjust the regex in the duplicate to reverse the commas and dots as it's assuming 1,200.02 (for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use:

[`([0-9]{1,3}(?:.[0-9]{3})*\,[0-9]+)\s?€`](https://regex101.com/r/UstoN1/2)

This will match in a capturing group 1-3 digits. Then repeats in a group a dot and 3 digits and at the end will match a comma followed by one or more digits.

After the capturing group `\s?[€]` is matches but is not part of the group.

If you want to match exactly 2 digits after the comma you could update `,[0-9]+` to `,[0-9]{2}`

As an alternative you could match your value without a capturing group and use a positive lookahead `(?=\s?[€])` to assert that what is on the right side is an optional whitespace character followed by `€`

[`[0-9]{1,3}(?:.[0-9]{3})*\,[0-9]+(?=\s?€)`](https://regex101.com/r/UstoN1/1)

Answer (score 0):

i'm guessing you got that value in a variable or something , why not try get it with

```
$value = substr($dataReceivedFromA, 0, -1);  // returns "2.550,00 "
```

i really think there is no point in using regex here if you only wanna get rid of the sign