# Is it possible to construct a regular expression that matches numbers with thousands and decimals delimiters exchanged such as 1,000.00 and 1,000.00?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to build a regular expression in Javascript that matches numbers with , and . as delimiters of thousands and decimals and vice versa. It must match 1,000,000.00 and 1.000.000,00. So far I have this:

```js
/^(\d{1,3}(?:([,\.])\d{3}){1}(?:\2\d{3})*|\d+)(?:(?!\2)[,\.](\d*))?$/
```

but it does not match when the number does not have thousands delimitir and have decimals delimitir such as 100.00 or 100,00 for example. I think it's because the capturing group of the thousands delimiter is null.

Is it possible to build  such regular expression?

Comment: First google result is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917082/regular-expression-to-match-numbers-with-or-without-commas-and-decimals-in-text

Comment: **It must match 1,000,000.00 and 1,000,000.00** Aren't they both the same?

Comment: @Barmar, corrected, thank you.

Comment: I added another duplicate that allows comma as the decimal separator.

Comment: This is not something you'd be able to do correctly without rethinking what and where the dot / comma mean. Might as well be `[\d.,]+`