# Sentence segmentation with Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, nlp, text-segmentation

I am writing a script to split the text into sentences with Python. However I am quite bad with writing more complex regular expressions.

There are 5 rules according to which I wish to split the sentences. I want to split sentences if they:

```
* end with "!"  or
* end with "?"  or
* end with "..."  or
* end with "." and the full stop is not followed by a number  or
* end with "." and the full stop is followed by a whitespace
```

What would be the regular expression for this for Python?

Comment: Do you need to *retain* the ending characters?

Comment: Showing your previous attempts will be a nice addition to the question :)

Comment: So far I have a very basic code:

    import re
    splitter = r"\.(?!\d)"
    re.split(splitter, s)

But it splits "U.S.A" into three sentences and "Hey..." is four sentences

I don't need to retain the ending characters.

Comment: is using a library and option for you? If you are doing this to do some Natural Language processing I really advice you to take another approach.

Comment: The task is to write a simple algorithm on your own, so a library is not an option

Comment: Guess this and assignment or homework then. Take a look at this, it may give you some idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745592/sentence-segmentation-using-regex?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can literally translate your five bullet points to a regular expression:

```
!|\?|\.{3}|\.\D|\.\s
```

Note that I'm simply creating an alternation consisting of five alternatives, each of which represents one of your bullet points:

- `!`
- `\?`
- `\.{3}`
- `\.\D`
- `\.\s`

Since the dot (`.`) and the question mark (`?`) are special characters within a regular expression pattern, they need to be escaped by a backslash (`\`) to be treated as literals. The pipe (`|`) is the delimiting character between two alternatives.

Using the above regular expression, you can then split your text into sentences using [`re.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split).