# String formatting in Python: Showing a price without decimal points

Tags: python, decimal, string-formatting

I have a Dollar price as a `Decimal` with a precision of `.01` (to the cent.)

I want to display it in string formatting, like having a message `"You have just bought an item that cost $54.12."`

The thing is, if the price happens to be round, I want to just show it without the cents, like `$54`.

How can I accomplish this in Python? Note that I'm using Python 2.7, so I'd be happy to use new-style rather than old-style string formatting.

Comment: Look at this answer from [Removing Trailing Zeros in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5808014/63011)

Comment: @PaoloMoretti: I wouldn't want an algorithm. I'd want to use Python's built-in faculties. If impossible, I'll make my own algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
import decimal

a = decimal.Decimal('54.12')
b = decimal.Decimal('54.00')

for n in (a, b):
    print("You have just bought an item that cost ${0:.{1}f}."
          .format(n, 0 if n == n.to_integral() else 2))
```

where `{0:.{1}f}` means print the first argument as a float using the number of decimals in the second argument and the second argument is `0` when the number is actually equal to its integer version and `2` when is not which I believe is what you're looking for.

The output is:

> You have just bought an item that cost $54.12.
>
> You have just bought an item that cost $54

Comment: I don't think that's what he wants. He wants `$54.12` as output. Only if the value is `54.00` he wants the decimals chopped off.

Comment: What advantage adds the `decimal` module? It seems useless.

Comment: @Zenon: from [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html): "Unlike hardware-based binary floating point, the `decimal` module has a user-alterable precision (defaulting to 28 places) which can be as large as needed for a given problem."

Comment: @TimPietzcker Thanks for your comment. I certainly misunderstood the question. I've just updated the answer to cover both cases.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> import decimal
>>> n = decimal.Decimal('54.12') 
>>> print('%g' % n)
'54.12'
>>> n = decimal.Decimal('54.00') 
>>> print('%g' % n)
'54'
```

Comment: @DavidHall: Hey, you're right. Sorry. I'll retract my previous comment. Interestingly, the new formatting language doesn't work this way: `"{0:g}".format(decimal.Decimal("54.00"))` returns `54.00`!

Comment: This will round the number in some cases. For example `print('%g' % decimal.Decimal(54.99999))` outputs `55`.

Comment: Problem with this solution: `'%g' % 1000000 == '1e+06'`. Scientific notation is not a proper way to display dollar prices.

Comment: @RamRachum: Well then use jcollado's solution. It's the only way.

Answer (score 2):

Answer is taken from [Python Decimals format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389846/python-decimals-format)

```
>>> a=54.12
>>> x="${:.4g}".format(a)
>>> print x
   $54.12
>>> a=54.00
>>> x="${:.4g}".format(a)
>>> print x
   $54
```

Comment: Answer taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389846/python-decimals-format

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

**Note**: `x` is the original price.

```
round = x + 0.5
s = str(round)
dot = s.find('.')
print(s[ : dot])
```

Comment: That's an algorithm. I wouldn't want an algorithm. I'd want to use Python's built-in faculties. If impossible, I'll use an algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> dollars = Decimal(repr(54.12))
>>> print "You have just bought an item that cost ${}.".format(dollars)
You have just bought an item that cost $54.12.
```