# How to properly use string formatting in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, string-formatting

Ok, please bear with me, I'm completely new to this.  This is for school, and the exact syntax isn't important here for my assignment, but for my own personal knowledge I want to know a little more about string formatting.

whenever I use %f it defaults to 2 decimal places. Is there a string format that I can use on a float that will show the float with the number of decimals it actually has?

for instance my list contains 2.0, 2.01, 2.001, 2.0001 and I want to use a string format to print them as they look. Which format code would I use or how could I use %f properly if possible?

This is in Python 2.7 on Windows 7(if that matters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%g` may be what you're looking for:

```
>>> "%g, %g, %g, %g" % (2.1, 2.01, 2.001, 2.0001)
'2.1, 2.01, 2.001, 2.0001'
```

Comment: Ah, thank you that is exactly what I needed. For some reason I can't find the code list in the help docs.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert the float to a string, then when you print it, it will be displayed just as you wrote it.

```
>>> x = str(2.0)
>>> print(x)
2.0
>>> x = str(2.01)
>>> print(x)
2.01
>>> x = str(2.001)
>>> print(x)
2.001
>>> x = str(2.0001)
>>> print(x)
2.0001
```

(In fact, to be precise, in Python you're not actually converting the floating point object, but creating a string object that looks like it. But that's a bit outside of the scope of your question.)

**UPDATE**

Someone posted a way to remove trailing zeros from floating point numbers using the Decimal class, here: [Removing Trailing Zeros in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807952/removing-trailing-zeros-in-python)

Comment: I could do that, but I was hoping there was a one line print statement I could use. print '%f,%f,%f' % (2.0,2.01,2.001) returns 2.000000,2.010000,2.001000. Which is weird because a couple days ago it defaulted to 2 decimal places. But anyways, is there a modifier to remove the trailing 0's?

Comment: Here's a one line print statement that works: `print(','.join((str(2.0),str(2.01),str(2.001),str(2.0001))))`

Comment: I also updated the above answer with a link to a function someone wrote that drops the trailing zeros from floating point values. If my answers are helpful, please check the box to accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: That will be very useful for another project I'm working on, but a lot more complex than what I'm trying to do here. And I guess removing the "trailing" zeros wasn't the correct idea when I said it.