# python round leaving a trailing 0

Tags: python

I am trying to round a floating point number in python to zero decimal places.

However, the round method is leaving a trailing 0 every time.

```
value = 10.01
rounded_value = round(value)
print rounded_value
```

results in 10.0 but I want 10

How can this be achieved? Converting to an int?

Comment: Cancel that dupe; the answer there will work here too, but that is more of a happy coincidence.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Pass the rounded value to `int()` to get rid of decimal digits:

```
>>> value = 10.01
>>> int(round(value))
10
>>> value = 10.55
>>> int(round(value))
11
```

Answer (score 3):

Casting to an int would certainly be the easiest way. If you are hell-bent on keeping it a float here's how to do it courtesy of Alex Martelli:

```
print ('%f' % value).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
```

Comment: The answer in question was this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2440786/1872981

Answer (score 3):

`10.0` and `10` are the same `float` value. When you `print` that value, you get the string `10.0`, because that's the default string representation of the value. (The same string you get by calling `str(10.0)`.)

If you want a non-default representation, you need to ask for it explicitly. For example, using the [`format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) function:

```
print format(rounded_value, '.0f')
```

Or, using the other formatting methods:

```
print '{:.0f}'.format(rounded_value)
print '%.0f' % (rounded_value,)
```

The full details for why you want `'.0f'` are described in the [Format Specification Mini-Language](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec), but intuitively: the `f` means you want fixed-point format (like `10.0` instead of, say, `1.0E2`), and the `.0` means you want no digits after the decimal point (like `10` instead of `10.0`).

Meanwhile, if the *only* reason you `round`ed the value was for formatting… never do that. Leave the precision on the float, then trim it down in the formatting:

```
print format(value, '.0f')
```

Comment: it is worth pointing out that `round()` and `".0f"` can produce different results e.g., for `-0.5` (different rounding rules).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Yes, I tried to clarify that in the last paragraph, but I don't think it was very clear. Call `round` to round a float to another float; `format` to format a float as a string. Using either one when you mean the other is equally wrong. And sometimes, you will want to do both (as in my initial example, where I called `format` on the `rounded_value`).

Comment: Is it possible to have a dynamic value in the rounding amount? e.g. `{0:.{1}f}.format(value, decimals_count)`

Answer (score 1):

You'll find a function `number_shaver()` that cuts trailing zeros of numbers in the EDIT 2 of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5808661/551449).

[Another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5850342/551449) in the same thread explains how the regex in `number_shaver()` works.

I improved the regex in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5929469/551449) some days later.