# ELIMINATE DECIMAL USING to_csv Pandas

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I have a problem when I export to csv a dataframe. I have a column number for example 1520, but when I export to csv using to_csv , in te file I find the number 1520.0 with decimal, is possible eliminate the ".0" and only preserve the number "1520" ?

todo.to_csv('D:\prueba.csv', sep=',',header=False,index=False)

I had resolved with this code, but is complicate when I have a lot of columns

```
for i in range(81,698):
 print("Creacion de archivo LOTE_AMD_M{0}.csv".format(i))
 data = pandas.read_sql(sql2.format(i),cnxn)
 todo=pandas.concat([dat,data])

 ruta='D:\descarga\LOTE_AMD_M{0}.csv'.format(i)
 r=todo
 r=r.fillna('')

 archivo= open(ruta,"a")
 count=0
 for index,row in r.iterrows():
     d=''
     for j in list(todo):
         if j == 'C1':
             t=str(row[j])
             d+=",{0}".format(t[0:len(t)-2])
         else:    
             d+=",{0}".format(row[j])

     archivo.write(d[1:len(d)]+'\n')
     count+=1

     if count%1000==0:
         print("se han insertado ",count," lineas")

archivo.close()

print("termino Carga SQL Query")
```

Comment: Did you try specifying the `float_format` parameter?

Comment: Yes, I intent with float_format="%" , is this the correct form?

Answer (score 0):

This question is already answered by @abarnert in a similar question, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16763327/python-round-leaving-a-trailing-0

Basically, you should set the `float_format` parameter to `float_format='%.0f'`. That should do the job.