# Python Convert string to float or int dynamically

Tags: python, int

I have a string that I have to convert into int or float depending or the case :

```
What I have    => What I want
"548189848.54" => 548189848.54
"548189848.50" => 548189848.5
"548189848.00" => 548189848
```

Is it possible to do it ?

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: Yes, of course its possible. What did you try?

Comment: Do you want it actually converted to an integer, or just printed with trimmed trailing zeroes? If the latter, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807952/removing-trailing-zeros-in-python

Comment: I tried `float()` but it works only for the two first cases.

Comment: What format is your data in? Are they in a list? Or are they individual numbers that you'd like a function to convert them with?

Comment: i think this is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389846/python-decimals-format

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could convert to float and then use `round`:

```
inputs = [ "548189848.54", "548189848.50", "548189848.00" ]

for i in inputs:
    f = float(i)
    if round(f) == f:
        print int(f)
    else:
        print f
```

output:

```
548189848.54
548189848.5
548189848
```

You could also do the same thing using a list comprehension, like:

```
print [int(float(i)) if round(float(i)) == float(i) else float(i) for i in inputs]
```

output:

```
[548189848.54, 548189848.5, 548189848]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one line that should do it.

```
numbers = ["548189848.54", "548189848.50", "548189848.00"]
result = [int(float(x)) if int(float(x)) == float(x) else float(x)  for x in numbers]
```

Gives output:

```
print result
[548189848.54, 548189848.5, 548189848]
```

Comment: @L.Stephan it is shorter, but it's also incorrect!
    
    `int("123.456")
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10`

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do that:

```
a = float("548189848.54")
a = int(a) if abs(int(a) - a) == 0 else a
```

Comment: `548189848.00` is meant to be an `int` though

Comment: He wants to convert to int or decimal depending on whether the number is a whole number or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
num_str = "548189848.54"

if '.' in num_str:
    num = float(num_str)
else:
    num = int(num_str)
```

Comment: This would fail the poster's third test case. where he wanted to convert x.00 into int.

Answer (score 0):

```
str_a = "23423.00"

a = float(str_a)
if a % 1.0 == 0:
    a = int(a)
```

Comment: You should add some sort of explanation along with your answer...  What happens if you try "23423.000000000000000001" with your solution?

Comment: 23423.000000000000000001 is not a standard python float. float("23423.000000000000000001") = 23423 (the questions wanted float or int - the required accuracy was not stated - other then float).

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably get a lot of floating point precision errors if you try to do anything with Python floats. I suggest using the `Decimal` module:

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
getcontext().prec = 30 # alterable, default 28
notInt = Decimal("100.000000000000000000000001")
isInt = Decimal("100.0000000000000000000000000")
if (notInt == int(notInt)):
    notInt = int(notInt)
else:
    notInt = float(notInt)

if (isInt == int(isInt)):
    isInt = int(isInt)
else:
    isInt = float(isInt)

>>> type(isInt)
<type 'int'>
>>> type(notInt)
<type 'float'>
```

An illustration of the floating point errors:

```
>>> 5.0000000000000001 == 5
True
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a complex script that I used for similar stuff. It used `Decimal`

```
import decimal

def remove_zeros(num):
    """
    1.100000 --> 1.1
    1.0      --> 1
    1.010    --> 1.01
    0.0      --> 0
    000.0000 --> 0
    """
    num = str(num)
    try:
        dec = decimal.Decimal(num)
    except:
        raise Exception("Not a valid floating point or integer")
    tup = dec.as_tuple()
    delta = len(tup.digits) + tup.exponent
    digits = ''.join(str(d) for d in tup.digits)
    if delta <= 0:
        zeros = abs(tup.exponent) - len(tup.digits)
        val = '0.' + ('0'*zeros) + digits
    else:
        val = digits[:delta] + ('0'*tup.exponent) + '.' + digits[delta:]
    val = val.rstrip('0')
    if val[-1] == '.':
        val = val[:-1]
    if tup.sign:
        return '-' + val
    return val
```

Update: @Cyber already shares the related SO post, which I failed to find.

Answer (score 0):

Why not unnecessarily involve some regex?

```
import re

def float_or_int(s):
    m = re.match('([+-]?\d+)(?:\.(?:0+|$)|$)', s)
    if m:
        return int(m.group(1))
    else:
        return float(s)
```

With your examples:

```
strings = ("548189848.54", "548189848.50", "548189848.00")
map(float_or_int, strings)
# [548189848.54, 548189848.5, 548189848]
```

Answer (score 0):

This also supports lists:
https://gist.github.com/pschwede/8d0f9d5f632c2f1fae17

```
def to_value(string):
    """Converts a string to the value it represents.
    If a non-string has been given, it stays as it is.

    Examples:
        >>> to_value("foobar")
        "foobar"
        >>> to_value(12345)
        12345
        >>> to_value("12345")
        12345
        >>> to_value("3.1415")
        3.1415
        >>> to_value("1,2,1")
        [1, 2, 1]
        >>> to_value("1,a,.5")
        [1, "a", 0.5]
    """
    # try if converting int/float back to str looks equal to the original
    # string. Return the string otherwise.
    for type_ in [int, float]:
        try:
            return type_(string)
        except ValueError:
            continue

    # if there is a comma, it must be a list
    try:
        if "," in string:
            return [to_value(s) for s in string.split(",") if s]
    except AttributeError:
        # It's not splittable. Not a string.
        return string
    except TypeError:
        # It's not iterable. Unknown type.
        return string

    # Getting here means the string couldn't be converted to something else.
    # We will return a string then.
    return string
```