# Python function for removing zeroes right of decimal, including decimal point?

Tags: python, excel, decimal

I am using xlrd to read values from cells in an excel spreadsheet.
Whenever I detect a cell type = 2, then I know it is a number.
A number of 3 in cell will be returned as 3.0
And a number of 3.14 will be returned as 3.14

I will be converting numbers to text.
What function should I use to remove zeroes right of the decimal and the decimal?

The above 2 numbers should be 3 and 3.14

Comment: What do you want to happen if the Excel spreadsheet has "3.0" in it?

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807952/removing-trailing-zeros-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `str.rstrip()`, twice:

```
str_of_float.rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
```

This will remove trailing zeros, and if that leaves you with a trailing `.` it's removed as well.

Demo:

```
>>> '3.14'.rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
'3.14'
>>> '3.0'.rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
'3'
>>> '3000.0'.rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
'3000'
```

Don't be tempted to use `.rstrip('.0')`; it'll remove too many zeros:

```
>>> '3000.0'.rstrip('.0')
'3'
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use [format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) when printing values to strings. Using the [format specs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec), it gives a good deal of control over what is printed.