# How do you remove .0 from the end of a number?

Tags: python-3.x

When I get the output for `print(f"{usernum} divided by {dividenum} is {usernum / dividenum}.")` it will be something like 3.0 rather than 3

How would I remove the .0 from the end.

I'm very new at python.

Comment: Did you try `int(result)`?

Comment: This has already been answered. Check the link here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807952/removing-trailing-zeros-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing Trailing Zeros in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807952/removing-trailing-zeros-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
print(f"{usernum} divided by {dividenum} is {usernum / dividenum:.0f}.")
```

The `:.0f` [format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) is using the fixed-point precision format specifier to round to 0 decimal places. This is functionally the same as using the built-in round function on the resulting float with precision `None`.

Other ways of achieving this

```py
# Rounds to nearest whole number
print(f"{usernum / dividenum:.0f}")
print(f"{usernum / dividenum:.0g}")
print(f"{round(usernum / dividenum)}")
print(f"{int(usernum / dividenum)}")

# Convert to string and parse, doesn't round
print(f"{str(usernum / dividenum)[0]}")  # Inaccurate after 9
print(f"{str(usernum / dividenum).split('.')[0]}")
```

The approach needed will depend on your desired output precision.

Comment: Add text describing this option. Are there others?

Comment: Good call! I was up far too late. Added explanation and other examples.